# When is $\prod_{i=0}^\infty (I-x_i x_i^T)=0$ for zero-centered Gaussian $x_i$?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Suppose $x_i\in \mathbb{R}^d$ is sampled IID from $\mathcal{N}(0,H)$.  Let $A_i=(I-x_i x_i^T)$ and assume $d$ is large. What are necessary conditions for the following to converge with probability 1?

$$\prod_{i=0}^\infty A_i \overset{p}{\to} 0$$

Convergence in probability is hard, so optimization literature almost always replaces it with "convergence in the mean". I want to bound the size of the "gap" caused by this simplification.

Background:

- Iosif Pinelis found necessary and sufficient conditions [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/443200/7655) for isotropic $x_i$, no gap
- Jair Taylor [suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4663777/when-does-the-product-of-random-matrices-diverge#comment9853736_4663777) $\det A_i>1 \text{ a.s.}$, vacuous for Gaussian $x_i$
- "$d$ is large" fails to capture the notion of high-dimensionality if we allow some dimensions to have zero variance. Alternative is to say that "$R$ is large" where $R$ is "effective rank" of Bartlett [Section 3.1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.11300)
  $$R=\frac{\operatorname{Tr}(H)^2}{\operatorname{Tr}(H^2)}$$
- Spectral radius $\rho$ [provides](http://yaroslavvb.com/convergence.pdf) necessary and sufficient conditions for $\prod_i A_i$ to converge in the mean
  $$\rho(2H+hh^TH^{-1})<2$$

  . where $H$ is diagonal and $h$ is a vector of diagonal entries

**Update Apr 12 2023**
I see numerical evidence that "convergence in the mean" and "convergence in probability" become equivalent when $H$ is diagonal with entries proportional to $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots,\frac{1}{d}$ and $d$ is large.

For $d=1$ I can take an instance where distribution converges in the mean and scale it some amount. The result is divergence in the mean, but convergence in probability. Here's distribution of $\|a_{\text{step}}\|^2$ where $a_{\text{step}+1}=A_\text{step} a_\text{step}$

[image]

On other hand with $d=100$, it appears hard to find such scenario. Either both "in the mean" and "in probability" converge, or they both diverge.
[image]

- Python [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t-BwH7biXFApGOmD9xPc0WVbLAlf_Rx8?usp=sharing)
- Mathematica [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/mathoverflow-gaussian-convergence.nb)

Comment: I would like to know what set (lowercase) h belongs to and how it is quantified, since these things are left unmentioned.

Comment: Some [background](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848) on this problem

Comment: @DanielAsimov looks like $h$ was not really needed, I replaced it with $H$ which is an arbitrary covariance matrix